# Tangle / wadded String on floor

Tags: calculus, geometry, functions, continuity

The rectangle in the figure represents the floor of a room, and AB a straight piece of string lying on the floor whose ends touch the opposite walls W1 and W2. The tangle represents the same piece of string wadded up and thrown back down on the floor. Show that there is at least one point of the wadded string whose distances from the two walls are exactly the same as they were before.

[image: Figure]

**My attempt**

What I tried is I checked for simple orientations about different point on the floor like i) if the string is rotated about any of its point (and it gives out points that satisfy)

For the string kept horizontal all the points on the string satisfy

For the string rotated 90° and translated left or right on the floor, there exists a point P that satisfy the condition as (the new orientation is the horizontal string rotated 90° about that required point P.)

[image: attempt]

*Also it is true for the string to be straight making any angle with horizontal.*

[image: String making angle with line perpendicular to wall]

**So point P lies at a distance of a/(1-cosθ) from the left end.**

***I have also shown for a square loop of side length L/4***

[image: square looped string]

**Also works for simple bends like circular arc (I have shown for semicircle)**

[image: thread bent in semicricle]

**I also did it generally for any arbitrary shape and understood what to prove but I can't go an inch ahead. Please have a look**
[image: arbitrary wadded string]

I just can't think that for a random wadded string on a random location on the floor.

I guess this can be proved using mean value theorem/intermediate or extreme value theorem. I can't see how to apply those in this case.

Comment: Posting a *homework* problem verbatim with zero effort is unacceptable. "See the preceding problem." Come on. This is insulting.

Comment: Sorry my bad about the mentioning of preceding problem.

Comment: Well I tried thinking of the tangle in different orientations like I) kept horizontal (all point of the string then satisfies.) ii) kept veritcal about the center( the center point would satisfy then) . iii) The L shaped string would do satisfy. The symmetric orientations do the job. But I can't come up with a solution for any tangle at anywhere on the floor. Can you provide some hint at least

Comment: Hint: We can describe the wadded string's position and shape using a function from a distance $t$ from one end of the string to a point $(x(t),y(t))$ within the room.

Comment: Is the Intermediate Value Theorem available for use in this problem?

Comment: @paw88789 Can't say as the equation of the tangle is random.( But since this is a question and asks us to prove so it must be true. Assuming it to be true we know that there exists such a point, just have to find a way to prove so.)

Comment: The two-dimensional picture distracts from the essence of the problem.  It is really a one-dimensional problem, for which the Intermediate Value Thm. gives a proof.

Comment: @TedShifrin Please check now. I mentioned everything I could put into this. Can you please provide some hint or advice or any step to follow? It would be much helpful.

Comment: @hardmath Can you please explain a bit more?  How was the wadded string not  two dimensional? Sorry, I couldn't understand that.

Comment: The problem asks only that you show some point on the string has the same (horizontal) $x$-coordinate when wadded up as it did originally stretched from left wall $W_1$ to right wall $W_2$.  Set up a function that gives the discrepancy between each point's $x$-coordinate in its wadded-up position and its original stretched-out position.

Comment: @hardmath yes got it and let's say the discrepancy (difference) between the path length EP and the Xo coordinate be set as 0 i.e.                                               Let's create a function say Z that gives the path length from end point to any desired point on the wadded string curve at Xo. So we now have path length EP = Z(Xo) and it is positive as it is length and Xo is also positive.Now we can set Z(Xo)- Xo= 0 and will result at least one value of Xo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
Let's create a function say Z that gives the path length from end point to any desired point on the wadded string curve at Xo. So we now have path length EP = Z(Xo) and it is positive as it is length and Xo is also positive.
0≤ Z(x)≤L ; L:length of string
We now create a function G(x) = Z(x)-x
We have,
0-x≤ G(x)≤L-x.      0≤ L- x ≤L as x∈ (a,b)

Thus by using a result of the Intermediate Theorem we get a point where G(x) =0 so there exists at least one such point.

[image: solution to the wadded string on floor]

Thanks a millions guys for such a nice response

Comment: If you like this flavor of mathematical reasoning, you might enjoy studying topology. This string problem is a simple case of the [Brouwer fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: @Karl Thank you. I would surely have this in my consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine two ants walk simultaneously along the two versions of the string, each at 1 cm/sec. The ant on the straight string starts out to the left of the one on the wadded string and ends up to the right of it, so at some moment the ants must have the same horizontal position. (Can you formalize this using the intermediate value theorem? Hint: a continuous function that goes from negative to positive must attain the value 0.) Therefore...

Comment: Yes this actually works and this is so true and indispensible way to think of ( those ants really helped me). Thanks a million Karl.